# Select from List to multiple List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

This is the goal: **Get a generic list of people and sort it in my model by Men, Women and Children...** I also renamed things for the sake of this site and my privacy.. Please focus on the lambda expression below! Thank you!

I get this error:

> Cannot convert from  `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project1.DataClasses.DataObjects.People>`

PeopleModel:

```
public List< People> Men { get; set; }
public List< People> Women { get; set; }
public List< People> Kids { get; set; }
public List< People> Babies { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetPeople(PeopleModels Peoples)
{
    List<People> listPeoples = new List<People>();

    listPeoples = DataClass.GetAllPeoples();

    // this is the code I cannot get to work.
    var men = listPeoples .Select(m => m.Sex == "M");
    Peoples.Men = men.ToList<People>();

    // Women, Children too..

    return View("Employees", Peoples);
}
```

Comment: What does Dataclass.GetAllPeoples() return?

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for the `Where` statement.

```
  // Get People wher the Sex = "M"
  Peoples.Men = listPeoples.Where(m => m.Sex == "M").ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are currently only selecting the `m.Sex` property and trying to assign its list to `List<People>` that is why the error. You can simply do:

```
Peoples.Men = listPeoples.Where(m => m.Sex == "M").ToList();
```

Also you don't need `Tolist<People>()`, simple `ToList()` would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand basics of the Linq queries. The
"Select" statement has to project results. For example:

```
var a = new List<string>{"ab", "abc", "abcd"};
var b = a.Select(x=>x.Length).ToList();
```

What happens here is a selection of lengths of all "a" elements and saving them to a variable b which is now `List<int>` containing `{2,3,4}`

What you need is the "Where" statement, which filters objects by predicate from a collection(any IEnumerable object)

```
var c = a.Where(x=>x.Length<4).Select(x=>x.Length).ToList();
```

Another syntax:

```
var c = (from element in a 
         where element.Length<4
         select x=>Length).ToList();
```

We say that **from** *elements* **in** *a* list we need to get *elements* **where** length is less than 4 characters and **select** all those lengths, put them **to list** and assign to *c* variable.

Recommend you to read more about topic and check [these](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) samples

Answer (score 1):

Your men collection contains  boolean  type items.

```
  var men = listPeoples .Select(m => m.Sex == "M"); // returns a boolean  collection     satisfying the condition
  Peoples.Men = listPeoples .Where(m => m.Sex == "M").ToList(); // This should be what you want
```

You could also do

```
var men = listPeoples .Where(m => m.Sex == "M");
Peoples.Men = men.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

With group you can get each of the types into their own collection:

```
var grouped = from person in people
    group person by person.Type into g
    select new {Key = g.Key, people = g};
```

The only problem is then selecting each collection, this is the best I got so far:

```
List<Person> men = new List<Person>(), women = new List<Person>(), children = new List<Person>(), babies = new List<Person>();

foreach (var persons in grouped)
{
    switch (persons.Key)
    {
        case PersonType.Male: men = persons.people.ToList(); break;
        case PersonType.Female: women = persons.people.ToList(); break;
        case PersonType.Child: children = persons.people.ToList(); break;
        case PersonType.Baby: babies = persons.people.ToList(); break;
    }
}
```